# Telling display to use scalar instead of variable

Tags: stata

Consider the following toy example:

```
clear
set obs 5

generate basicvar = 3
scalar b = 27
```

To my surprise, this produces the following output:

```
. display b
3
```

This is contrary to the expected value of `27`. In other words, Stata interprets `b` as `basicvar[1]` rather than my scalar `b`.

How can I tell Stata that I really mean my scalar instead of some variable, which happens to start with the same letter?

I understand that I could also use some other name for my variable but I am interested in the underlying logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
. display scalar(b)
27
```

Variable names always take precedence over scalars.